# How to define a templated method for objects, some of which are also templated

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have:

```
std::multimap< std::string, netCDF_Dimension > dimensions;
```

and similar multimaps.
Occasionally I need:

```
std::multimap< std::string, netCDF_Attribute<U> > attributes;
```

where U is, for example, a netCDF_VarAtt or netCDF_GlobalAtt.

I can write a search function:

```
    template<class T>
    boost__optional<T*> Search(const std::multimap< std::string, T > currMap){
      //Search in map.
      if found
          return T*;
      else
          return boost::none
    }
```

This compiles for standard types/classes but not for `netCDF_Attribute<U>`. This is beyond my simple understanding of templates. What I need is:

```
T = netCDF_Attribute<U>
```

as well as the obvious types, is there a solution to this?

This code below compiles for with simple types/classes`netCDF_Attribute<U>`

The full code of the calling class is:

```
template<typename U>
class netCDF_Attributes{
  std::multimap< std::string, netCDF_Attribute<U> > attributes;
public:

  boost::optional< std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > > Find(std::vector< std::string >::const_iterator currStep, 
                                  std::vector< std::string >::const_iterator lastStep);
  void Initialise( std::multimap< std::string, U > &attMap );
};

template<typename U>
boost::optional< std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > >  netCDF_Attributes< U >::Find(std::vector< std::string >::const_iterator currStep, 
                                             std::vector< std::string >::const_iterator lastStep){
  netCDF_Crawler crawl;
  return crawl.Find(attributes, currStep, lastStep);
}

template<typename U>
void netCDF_Attributes< U > :: Initialise(std::multimap< std::string, U > &attMap ){
  for ( auto iter : attMap )
    attributes.insert( std::pair< std::string,  netCDF_Attribute< U > >( iter.first,  netCDF_Attribute< U >(iter.second) ) ); 
}

enum netCDF_Element {groupElement, attributeElement, dimensionElement, variableElement, dataElement};

class netCDF_Crawler {
public:
  template<typename T>
  boost::optional<T * > Shallow_Search_List(const std::multimap< std::string, T > &currMap, std::string name);
  template<typename T>
  boost::optional< std::pair<netCDF_Element, void *> > Deep_Search_List(const std::multimap< std::string, T > &currMap,
                                       std::vector< std::string >::iterator currStep, 
                                       std::vector< std::string >::iterator lastStep);
  template<typename T>
  boost::optional< std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > > Find(const std::multimap< std::string, T > &currMap,
                                std::vector< std::string >::iterator currStep, 
                                std::vector< std::string >::iterator lastStep);
};

  template<typename T>
  boost::optional<T * > netCDF_Crawler::Shallow_Search_List(const std::multimap< std::string, T > &currMap, std::string name){
    for (auto iter : currMap)
      if (iter.first == name)
    return &iter.second;
    return boost::none;
  }

template<typename T>
  boost::optional< std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > > netCDF_Crawler::Deep_Search_List(const std::multimap< std::string, T > &currMap,
                                               std::vector< std::string >::iterator currStep, 
                                               std::vector< std::string >::iterator lastStep){
    for (auto iter : currMap)
      if ( boost::optional< std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > > res = iter.second.Find(currStep, lastStep) )
    return res;
    return boost::none;
  }

template<typename T>
  boost::optional< std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > > netCDF_Crawler::Find(const std::multimap< std::string, T > &currMap,
                                        std::vector< std::string >::iterator currStep, 
                                        std::vector< std::string >::iterator lastStep){

    if (boost::optional< T* > currPtr = Shallow_Search_List< T >(currMap, *currStep))
      // Found in map.
      // This was the last element to find.
      if (currStep == lastStep)
    return std::pair< netCDF_Element, void * > ((*currPtr)->element, (void *) *currPtr);
      else
    // Try and find the next element
    return (*currPtr)->Find(currStep+1, lastStep);
    // Not found in curr map.  Dig deeper. Look in subgroups.
    else 
      return Deep_Search_List<T>(currMap, currStep, lastStep);
    return boost::none;
  }
```

And the first error message is:

```
Class_netCDF_Attributes.hpp: In instantiation of
‘boost::optional<std::pair<netCDF_Element, void*> > netCDF_Attributes<U>::Find
  (std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, 
   std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator)
[with U = netCDF::NcVarAtt;
 std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator = 
   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’:
Class_netCDF_Variable.hpp:55:98:   required from here
Class_netCDF_Attributes.hpp:34:51: error: no matching function for call to 
‘netCDF_Crawler::Find(std::multimap<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, netCDF_Attribute<netCDF::NcVarAtt>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, netCDF_Attribute<netCDF::NcVarAtt> > > >&,
                      std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator&,
                      std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator&)’
   return crawl.Find(attributes, currStep, lastStep);
```

Comment: DR; TL; I think you would need template template parameters.

Comment: Hmm. Objects can't be "templated". Objects are instances of existing types.

Comment: Yes, but I still can't work out how to get the template to treat an "existing type" (correction from 'object') and a templated "existing type" as the same.

Comment: Changed "objects" to "types" as suggested.

Comment: shouldn't this `boost::optional< T* > currptr` be `boost::optional< T > * currPtr` instead. Otherwise you are recursively creating new classes. additionally you are dereferencing `currPtr` which is currently not a pointer

Comment: Your first sample code is full of errors.  I fixed your error message to be a code literal, but it clearly is only part of the full, real errors you got.  Your code *copies* the map, which is a bad idea.  The code you post does not generate the error you posted (the error is clearly when you *call* the function, not when you define it, and you only posted the definition).  Meanwhile, the body of the function, which you did post, is *probably* unrelated to the error; unless the error occurs in the body!

Comment: Please 1) pass the `multimap` by `const` reference. 2) post the full code 3) post the *first* error message it creates. Failing 2&3, we will have to close your post, as it is not useful/cannot be answered ...

Comment: Have no idea why you are getting the error, the code is too long-winded and you are not showing all of it. Perhaps an MCVE is in order. But why are you passing std::multimap by value? You are killing any performamce advantage multimap may provide over a simple linear container.

Comment: @101010 It must be possible to do this without template template parameters.

Comment: @walter Done items 1, 2, and 3.  Unless you want me to post the other classes as well.

Comment: @n.m How do I make it less "long-winded"?  What is MCVE?

Comment: @MartinT you added the irrelevant code of the member functions of `class netCDF_Crawler` but you failed to include the offending piece of code causing the error (`netCDF_Attributes::Find()`) and your error message is scrambled (what is a `std::vector >::const_iterator`???). Please fix.

Comment: @MartinT When you see an unfamiliar term, enter it into a search engine.  If you get a definition, and the definition is hosted on *the same website* as the term was used, possibly that is what the other person was talking about.  ;)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The idea is, you have an error that you don't understand.  You remove code you think is  unrelated to the error.  You recompile.  Still get error?  Good!  Repeat.  Error gone?  Roll back, confirm error, then delete *different* code.  Continue until code is minimal, complete and verifiable.

Comment: @MartinT Try to use a different compiler in the hope that the error message is more useful (clang has often superior error messages to gcc). I couldn't verify your problem with a very minimal code of similar kind -- perhaps it's a compiler bug? Or perhaps `crawl` (in the undisclosed `crawl.Find(attributes, currStep, lastStep);`) is `const`?

Comment: @Walter  I added the netCDF_Attributes code.

Comment: @Walter  I will try and install and run with clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**: you provide the wrong argument types.

This is hard to spot in your code, because it's rather cluttered. So, the way to get to the bottom of this is by first reducing the problem to a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Here is a pretty small version reproducing your error:

```
struct netCDF_Crawler {
  template<typename T>
  T find(std::multimap<std::string,T> const&, std::vector<std::string>::iterator);
};

template<typename U>
struct netCDF_Attribute { U i=U{}; };

template<typename U>
struct netCDF_Attributes
{
  std::multimap<std::string,netCDF_Attribute<U>> attributes;
  netCDF_Attribute<U> find(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator step)
  {
    netCDF_Crawler crawl;
    return crawl.find(attributes,step);
  }
};

template struct netCDF_Attributes<int>;
```

From looking at *this* code the error is obvious, but let's see what clang says (btw, the second very helpful note is only produced after reducing the number of arguments of `find()` from 3 to 2):

```
test.cc:21:18: error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
    return crawl.find(a,step);
           ~~~~~~^~~~
test.cc:25:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'netCDF_Attributes<int>::find'
  requested here
template struct netCDF_Attributes<int>;
                ^
test.cc:7:5: note: candidate function [with T = netCDF_Attribute<int>] not viable:
 no known conversion from '__wrap_iter<const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<pointer>'
 for 2nd argument
  T find(std::multimap<std::string,T> const&, std::vector<std::string>::iterator);
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Upon inspection, we see that `netCDF_Crawler::find` takes an `iterator` as second argument, while `netCDF_Attributes::find()` provides a `const_iterator`. Obviously, that's not going to work. I leave it to you to fix.

Comment: Oh, dear me.  Many thanks for the solution, but especially for the instruction and persistence (Also thanks  to the other responders).

Comment: @MartinT you're welcome. I don't mind if you upvote and accept my answer, though.

Comment: It was only coincidence that all the non-templated types had the non-const iterator, whereas the only time I used a templated type I made the mistake of using a const_iterator.  Furthermore, the error message from g++ was not very helpful.

Comment: The error message was somewhat helpful and with some more experience you would have spotted the error immediately.